# Calling ffmpeg from php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I need to run ffmpeg from a php script. The ffmpeg wiki page on the same topic (http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Using%20FFmpeg%20from%20PHP%20scripts) suggests using shell_exec over ffmpeg-php. Some other pages suggests using ffmpeg-php. Which method is better? Is ffmpeg-php compatible with latest versions of php? My only purpose is to convert any videos hosted by the user into mp4 (h.264,aac).

Answer (score 0):

Exec() will always give you more control. I can't find any function at the ffmpeg-php to do what you need to do in the other hand, so I'd choose to execute it as a command. :)